# nginx.conf redirecta a full url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I want to redirect a full url using nginx.
This doesn't work:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain1.com www.domain2.com www.domain3.com ;

if ($http_host$request_uri ~ www.domain2.com/hello.html) {
    rewrite ^  google.com  permanent;
   }

}
```

What is the correct way to do this?
I doubt whether the variable $http_host$request_uri can match to that address.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `if` cannot deal with expressions very well. I'd rewrite your configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain1.com www.domain2.com www.domain3.com;

    set $full_url $http_host$request_uri;
    if ($full_url ~ ^www\.domain2\.com/hello\.html) {
       return 301 https://google.com;
    }
}
```

It might be too late for you but It resolved my problem and I hope it helps someone...